# Plot 3rd order polynomial in y

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to plot a function of format `a*y**3 + b(x)*y**2 + c(x)*y + d(x)` in gnuplot.

**Edit:** To clear out what I'm trying to plot, these are the expressions for `b(x), c(x), d(x)`:

```
b(x) = b1 + b2*x
c(x) = c1 + c1*x + c2*x**2
d(x) = d1 + d1*x + d2*x**2 + d3*x**3
```

`a, b1, ... , d2, d3` are constants, which I know.

I was wondering if there's any way to give gnuplot a `f(x,y)` function and it would figure out (numerically) the plot.

**Edit 2:** Doing stuff in the middle of the night is not always a good idea... Obviously what I was requesting would be surface levels, but in fact I'm interested in plotting `f(x,y) = 0`

Comment: You're probably being downvoted because you aren't asking about something specific you can't figure out – you's just asking someone to solve your general problem.  I'd like to get the centrifuge operating costs for all wastewater plants in major cities - how can I get the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
set contour
unset surface
set view map
set cntrparam levels discrete 0
splot a*y**3 + b(x)*y**2 + c(x)*y + d(x)
```

Comment: This is just mgilsons answer. You should accept that, instead of your own.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite easy:

```
gnuplot> b1=1.
gnuplot> b2=2.
gnuplot> c1=1.
gnuplot> c2=2.
gnuplot> d1=2.
gnuplot> d2=3.
gnuplot> d3=4.
gnuplot> b(x) = b1 + b2*x
gnuplot> c(x) = c1 + c1*x + c2*x**2
gnuplot> d(x) = d1 + d1*x + d2*x**2 + d3*x**3
gnuplot> a = 3.0
gnuplot> splot a*y**3 + b(x)*y**2 + c(x)*y + d(x)
```

I just made up a bunch of constants, but you get the idea.  The thing that you might be missing is that since you're plotting a function of 2 variables (x and y), you need to use `splot`.  What I've done is plotted it as a surface, but you can also plot it as a "heat map" on the surface if you use `pm3d`

```
gnuplot> splot a*y**3 + b(x)*y**2 + c(x)*y + d(x) w pm3d
```

Or as a map:

```
gnuplot> set view map
gnuplot> splot a*y**3 + b(x)*y**2 + c(x)*y + d(x) w pm3d
```